# Searching for a way to add logs on the top of each function - something like trace

Tags: objective-c, logging, trace

I found that if I added `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled=YES` to the argument, xCode create for me in run time a file with the methods trace.
For example: 
z: appdelegete:didfinishlaunching
z: addElement
...

I don't find the file.

Answer (score 1):

From [Technical Note TN2124](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html)

> If you set the NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled environment variable to
>   "YES", the Objective-C runtime will log all dispatched Objective-C
>   messages to a file named /tmp/msgSends-pid/.